# OptionA: Estimate Numbers

Tags: python

This is part of my code for my school work, so please understand that I may not understand your answer fully:

The task:

**OptionA:** Must ask the user for the estimate number (from paintingJobs.txt)
•   It must find the CustomerID and Estimate details for the entered estimate number

However, when I enter an estimate number from the paintingJobs.txt file e.g. A001, it doesn't display the information on the estimate number A001 and just prints out the message "That isn't a valid estimate number. Please try again."

This is how the displayed outlook should look like: [PLEASE CLICK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oG9Km.png)
but of course with the headings in my code.

```
def optionA():
    estimate = input("Please enter the estimate number:")
    find = 0
    file = open("paintingJobs.txt", "r")
    print("*******************************")
    print("Your estimate number:", estimate)

    rows = csv.reader(file)
    for row in rows:
        estimateNumber, customerID, finalTotal, amountPaid, amountOut = row
        if estimate == estimateNumber:
            cont = False
            print("")
            print("Estimate Number: {0}".format(listed[0]))
            print("CustomerID: {0}".format(listed[1]))
            print("Final Total: {0}".format(listed[2]))
            print("Amount Paid: {0}".format(listed[3]))
            print("Estimate Date {0}".format(listed[4]))
            print("Status: {0}".format(listed[5]))
            find = 1
            None
            break
        if(find == 0):
            print("That isn't a valid estimate number. Please try again.")
        return optionA()
```

Comment: is this the correct indentation?

Comment: @Keiwan The indentation in my code is fine, but now I've edited the indentation here

Comment: python 2.x or python 3.x? If you're using python 2.x, change `input("Please enter the estimate number:")` to `raw_input("Please enter the estimate number:")` to avoid trying to compare integers and strings.

Comment: The indentation shown here might accurately reflect what you've written, but it's presumptuous to call it *correct*. Consider this: How many lines of the file do you look at before printing the error message?

Comment: @jDo No I'm currently using python 3.x

Comment: @RobKennedy it starts at line 39: estimateNumber, customerID, finalTotal, amountPaid, amountOut = row, but I don't know how to fix this problem

Comment: No, I meant how many lines of the *input file* does your program read? Hint: The answer is 1. Why do you suppose that is? Has the loop finished running at the time the error message is printed? Why do you think I'm asking these questions in relation to a comment about indentation?